# How to delete an existing csv file and create new one in ssis?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to ssis. I want to schedule a job to create a csv file daily. So each day, the existing file should be deleted and I want to create a new csv file. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You can try using a `FileSystem task`, but I don't know how it handles exceptions (e.g. file doesn't exist on first call). However, I usually create a small Scripttask (C#) where I check if the file exists and perform the deletion basing on the result of this check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for deleting existing file, the flat file connection properties should have a tick box to overwrite the existing file. If the file is not locked by another process like Excel that should be sufficient to ensure the old one is replace by the new one

If you need more guidance on how to build the package you can have a look at the below link

[Exporting to CSV](https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-dynamically-generated-csv-files-containing-sql-server-data/)